# wchar_t array passed into function

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio-2010, sizeof, wchar-t

I am making a C program on windows using visual studio 2010.

I am passing a wchar_t array to a function.

```
//in main
wchar_t bla[1024] = L"COM6";

mymethod(bla);

static void mymethod(wchar_t *bla) {
    //do stuff
}
```

I used the debugger to watch bla, sizeof(bla) and noticed that in main, bla is of type `wchar_t` and `sizeof(bla) = 2048` but in mymethod, bla is of type `unsigned short*` and has `sizeof(bla) = 4`.

Why is this the case?

I wanted to pass bla into the method so that the method could change the array instead of returning an edited array. However, swprintf is not working as I want sizeof(bla) to be 1024 instead of 4.

Cheers.

Comment: Array decays to a pointer when passed to functions. Just use `[]` on pointer as usually you do with arrays in the function. It should work. But the function don't know the size of array. Have another parameter to `mymethod` which says the size of the array being passed.

Comment: `sizeof(bla)` returns just the size of an pointer on your enviornment since,`bla` is of the type `unsigned short *` `sizeof(pointer)` where `pointer` is pointer pointing to any datatype will be same on an system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in main you are calculating the size of the array:

```
sizeof(bla); // 1024 * sizeof(unsigned short) = 2048
```

in your function, if you use sizeof, you are calculating the size in bytes of a pointer:

```
sizeof(bla); //means sizeof (wchar_t *) = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it odd that the argument function is of type `wchar_t` in VS2010, its been a long time since `wchar_t` was just a typedef for `unsigned short`. The difference size is obvious since one is an array and the other is a pointer. If this were C++ you could take a reference to the array. You won't be able to get the size of the array from within `mymethod` so if you need it, add it as another parameter.